# Static Character Inventory After File Transfer Terraria Mobile

Tags: android, terraria-mobile

Hello I am using a GS3 and have recently flashed CM12.1. I backed up my character and 2 worlds from the data/data/terrariasomething/files and put them into this folder once I got the new OS and reinstalled Terraira. My character now has an inventory that remains the same as the backup file. It can be edited (in the game) but when relogged it is back to what it was on the backup made.

The world's chests and terrain can be edited and that is saved but not the character's inventory. Any changes to it are simply overtwritten when relogging to what the backup I put in had. Creating a new character works and that character saves, but then I would lose my 10 mana and 500 health so it isnt really my desired solution. I am and have run only vanilla Terraria.

Am I somehow not allowing editing tomy character when it is on a new phone? Is there some sort of nonrecognition by the game that this file from my old OS is a player that can be edited? Is the file somehow corrupt?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you haven't found a fix yet, then start the game with your backed up saves (player and world) and then go to your saved file in data/data/ and find your old save file(s) and delete the old ones, then go back into the game and save the game again. After restarting again, you should have everything renewed from this play, instead of the old saves.

Make sure you backup your backups first, this way you don't lose what you already have.